# How do I let "TemporaryDirectory" in python inherit the parent directory's permission?

Tags: python, linux, unix, temporary-directory

I'm creating a temporary directory in python using `from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory`. How do I create a TemporaryDirectory in python and force its permission to be the same as the folder that it is created in?

Unfortunately, the items in TemporaryDirectory are not accessible by another program I have running. This program does have access to TemporaryDirectory's parent directory but not TemporaryDirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see support for it directly in `TemporaryDirectory`, and indeed the mode `0o700` is [hard-coded](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/485e715cb1ff92bc9882cd51ec32589f9cb30503/Lib/tempfile.py#L360) into the tempfile package, but you could use `chmod`.  Example:

```
with TemporaryDirectory(dir=parent) as tmpdir:    
    os.chmod(tmpdir, os.stat(parent).st_mode)

    os.system("ls -ld " + parent)
    os.system("ls -ld " + tmpdir)
```

The question only asked for permissions, but if you also require changing *ownership* (user or group), then look at `os.chown` and the `st_uid` and `st_gid` properties of the `stat_result` object (analogous to `st_mode` above). Note that some operations may require root privileges.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for a direct way without needing to do this

Comment: @Goldname This is not going to be possible - answer edited to reflect why (see link where I wrote "hard-coded").